# react-chartjs-2 keep x axis always 0% to 100%

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I am trying to create a **react-chartjs-2** Bar graph.

I want to keep the **x axis** always **0% to 100%**.

Now the graph displays only the maximum % in x axis (if 80% is the x value then x axis max is set as 80)

```
scales: {
  x: {
    ticks: {
      color: "white",
      beginAtZero: true,
      max: 100%,
    },
    grid: {
      display: false, // Hide x grid
    },
  },
  y: {
    ticks: {
      color: "white",
    },
    grid: {
      display: false, // Hide y grid
    },
  },
},
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the [docs for the Chart component options](https://react-chartjs-2.js.org/components/chart) they point to the [Chart.js docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/) where the max scale is set under a `scale` attribute, you have it inside the `ticks` property, try:

```
...
  x: {
    ticks: {
      color: "white",
      beginAtZero: true,
    },
    grid: {
      display: false, // Hide x grid
    },
    max: 100,
  },
...
```

Comment: this works only with 100 when i give 100% it gives error

Comment: I've change the number, I'm not familiar with Chartjs I just follow the docs, makes sense to have the tick unit values as whole numbers and not percentages

Comment: @meon the chart only accepts a numeric value, hence the error, you are working with percentages so you don't need to tell Charjs that the number is a percentage. The type of unit is only useful to the user so display the unit type on the chart labels.